# Running jTSS in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, trusted-computing

I am trying to run the Trusted Computing API JSR321 in Eclipse by following the tutorial provide at [Getting Started with JSR321](https://java.net/projects/jsr321/pages/GettingStartedGuide) in Windows 7.

After successfully enabling my TPM (manufacturer: STM & version: 1.2).

I tried to run the code given in the tutorial,

```
import javax.trustedcomputing.tpm.TPMContext;       

public class HellowWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{
            TPMContext context = TPMContext.getInstance();
            context.connect(null);
            //Do somthing cool here         
            context.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

I also added the external jar files as Classpaths in eclipse for the IAIK jTSS ([jTSS 0.7.1a](http://sourceforge.net/projects/trustedjava/files/jTSS%20%28Full%20Java%20%28tm%29%20TSS%29/jTSS%200.7.1a/)), they also mentioned that

> It is necessary to set the **jsr321.tpmcontextimpl** property to the classname of your TPMContext implementation. 
>   For example `java -cp YourClasspath -Djsr321.tpmcontextimpl=iaik.tc.jsr321.tpm.TPMContextImpl yourjavaapplication.class`

So I added the above code by right clicking on the project and going to the **Run As** -> **Run Configuration** and in the **Arguments** tab in the section provided for **VM arguments** I inserted the following command

```
-cp C:\Users\workspace\HelloWorld\bin -Djsr321.tpmcontextimpl=iaik.tc.jsr321.tpm.TPMContextImpl HellowWorld
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/trustedcomputing/tpm/TPMContext
   at HellowWorld.main(HellowWorld.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.trustedcomputing.tpm.TPMContext
   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
   ... 1 more
```

I have already added all the mentioned dependencies in **Java Build Paths** inside **Project Properties**.

Kindly suggest a solution.

Thanks